# How to send a bulk email with csv file and a jpg image attachments using gmailr

Tags: r, bulk-email, gmailr

I want to send a bulk email with an attachment. The list of receiving email addresses and the body of the email are in a CSV file as below.

[image]

I want to attach a CSV file and a JPG image to each email. I tried the following code, but I do not understand where to put the argument to attach the above files.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(gmailr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(plyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(purrr))
library(readr) 

#Assigning the client contact information file.
my_dat <- read_csv("ClientContactForm.csv") 

# creating a CSV file
write.csv(file = "iris.csv", iris)


#Assigning Company name, sender,BCC and body
this_hw <- "Miller Logistics"
email_sender <- 'Miller Logistics <manoj.rasika99@gmail.com>'
optional_bcc <- 'Anonymous <01manojrasika10@gmail.com>'
body <- "Dear, %s %s

%s.
Thanks for desiding to transport with us!

our web site
https://www.predictea.com/

Best Regards,
Miller
"
#Creating the dataframe with above information and subject
edat <- my_dat %>%
  mutate(
    To = sprintf('%s <%s>', Name, Email),
    Bcc = optional_bcc,
    From = email_sender,
    Subject = sprintf('Logistics Options for %s %s', Mr_or_Miss, Surname),
    body = sprintf(body, Name, Surname, Text)) %>%
  select(To, Bcc, From, Subject, body) 
write_csv(edat, "data-frame.csv")

# This allow to have html links embedded in the body
emails <- edat %>%
  pmap(gm_mime,attr = list(content_type = "text/html"))
str(emails, max.level = 2, list.len = 2)

#creating mime object
emails <- plyr::dlply(edat, ~ To, function(x) gm_mime(
  To = x$To,
  Bcc = x$Bcc,
  From = x$From,
  Subject = x$Subject,
  body = x$body))

# trying to attach the CSV file to the email 
emails <- gm_attach_file(emails,"iris.csv") 

#sending emails
safe_send_message <- safely(send_message) 

sent_mail <- emails %>% 
  map(safe_send_message)
```

When I execute the code, emails deliver successfully, but without the attachment.
Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say based on how you wrote the question but basically you need to get the `gm_attach_file` as part of the `gm_mime(...)` step. Does this work?

```
#creating mime object
emails <- plyr::dlply(edat, ~ To, function(x) gm_mime(
  To = x$To,
  Bcc = x$Bcc,
  From = x$From,
  Subject = x$Subject,
  body = x$body) %>%
 gm_attach_file("iris.csv", type = "csv"))


#sending emails
safe_send_message <- safely(send_message) 

sent_mail <- emails %>% 
  map(safe_send_message)
```

Comment: Thank you for your directions to insert the ```gm_attach_file()``` in to mime object, I managed to find a solution as shown below

Answer (score 0):

Created this function

```
prepare_and_send <- function(sender, recipient,
                             title, text,
                             attachment) {
  email <- gm_mime() %>%
    gm_to(recipient) %>%
    gm_from(sender) %>%
    gm_subject(title) %>%
    gm_html_body(text) %>%
    gm_attach_file(attachment, type = "pdf")
  email <- gm_attach_part(email,msg) %>%
    gm_send_message() 
}
```

Then iterate through the email addresses in the CSV file

```
addresses %>%
  mutate(
    to = sprintf('%s <%s>', name, email),
    from = email_sender,
    subject = sprintf('Logistic options for %s', name),
    msg = sprintf('Dear %s, %s',name,info),
    attachment = sprintf('%s.pdf', attach)) %>%
  mutate(x = pmap(list(from, to, subject, msg, attachment),
                  safely(prepare_and_send)))
```